# How to convert a ref type to its "non ref" equivalent?

Tags: c#, reflection

Suppose I have the following:

```
var t = typeof(Foo).MakeByRefType();
```

are there any ways to convert the result back to `typeof(Foo)`?

Honestly, the only way I've found is this:

```
var t = typeof(Foo).MakeByRefType();
string name = t.Name.Trim('&');
string asmQualified = t.AssemblyQualifiedName.Replace(t.Name, name);
var v = Type.GetType(asmQualified);
```

Other methods I've tried doesn't seems to work:

1. Are there better ways to do this?
2. If this is the only way, are there situations in which it can fail (maybe with dynamically generated assemblies)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what [`GetElementType()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getelementtype(v=vs.110).aspx) is for. Despite the name, it doesn't just work to get the element of an array type, it also works to get the type referred to by a pointer or ref type.

Comment: Thanks! In fact I tought it was only for getting types of elements contained in arrays.